How to backup/export Samsung Notes to PC
Is there a way to do this? I need it to be in a usable format on the computer. If the solution is complicated, please explain it in layman language as much as possible.  My version of Samsung Notes is 4.4.10.71. Thanks for your help!

Related: Opening .memo files from Samsung default memo app

Does this answer your question? I installed another SMS application, now I get notified twice

No, Rohit, that has nothing to do with what I'm talking about.

I have a newer Notes version and in that I can select one or more notes and from the three dots menu select Save as File.

Thank you, Robert! That works. There is a problem with it, though. You have to choose a file type, like microsoft word, text, pdf, etc. And it will only save your notes that are compatible with that, but it won't tell you which notes were exluded. Ex. a note with a pic can't be saved as a text file. So I tried saving all my notes as both text and Mic Word. I have 50 notes total. 46 got saved as word. 43 as text. 3 of them have pictures, that explains why 3 didn't get saved as text. However, I have no idea which are those 4 that didn't get saved at all. It'll be a pain to find out manually.

Robert, if you post your solution as an answer, I can mark it as an answer. I don't know why people put answers as comments (someone let me know if you know why people do this, I'm new to Stack Exchange). Cheers.
